# javascript:window.location.href opens new tab in firefox and new window (rather as a pop up ) in IE . I want the page to open in the same window

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

What do I need to change in the line below ? Please help . Thanks :)

```
 lstItems.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:window.location.href='" + Project2.Constants.MySiteURL + "myPage.aspx/" + ID + "';");
```

edit:-

i found this solution on SO but dont know how to use it in my case :/

```
window.open("http://asdf.com", "window_name","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=no,width=650,height=650");
```

edit 2 :-

Any Javascript expert in here ?? Please help me out.

edit3 :-

@Headshota:: Its still opening in new tab in firefox and as apop up window in IE :(

edit 4 :-

@ Craig :: What does this mean? "possibly got a misplace target="_blank" somewhere" How do i check for it??

edit :-

Could someone please help me out with this ? :(

I have tried whatever I could but i just can't get the page to open in the same window. Please someone  help me out.

Comment: You don't want to use `window.open`, that will open a new window or tab (depending on browser and the user's configuration options). What HTML is being produced by your first one? And what happens if you assign to just `window.location` rather than `window.location.href`?

Comment: @mu is too short : -  I changed it to just window.location..still the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need `javascript:` in your code.

```
lstItems.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.location.href='" + Project2.Constants.MySiteURL + "myPage.aspx/" + ID + "';");
```

Comment: : Its still opening in new tab in firefox and as apop up window in IE :(

Answer (score 0):

I use window.location.href all the time and it doesn't open a new tab. I think you may have changed a setting in Firefox or possibly got a misplace target="_blank" somewhere.

Comment: @ Craig :: What does this mean? "possibly got a misplace target="_blank" somewhere" How do i check for it??

Comment: When an anchor tag has target="_blank" attribute it will open in a new window or tab.

Comment: I just set target's value to "_parent" but it still is opening in new window and new tab in firefox

Answer (score 0):

```
//This will open google.com in the current tab.
openUILinkIn("http://www.google.com","current");

//This will open yahoo.com in the new tab.
openUILinkIn("http://www.yahoo.com","tab");
```

Comment: as far as I know: this is not a public function - it's a helper, internal function working only in FF.